# How to implement self and __init__() in julia

Tags: julia, self

I would like to know what is the correct approach to implement `self` and `__inti__()` in Julia?

## Example

```py
class rectangle:
   def __init__(self, length, breadth, height):
      self.length = length
      self.breadth = breadth
      self.height = height
   def get_area(self):
      return self.length * self.breadth
r = rectangle(160, 20, 1000)
print("area is", r.get_area())
```

I have tried this in Julia, but it does neither fits the operation expectation nor the results.

```
struct rectangle
    length
    breadth
    height
end

function __init__(rectangle) 
    rectangle.length = length
    rectangle.breadth = breadth
    rectangle.height = height
end
function get_area(rectangle)
    return rectangle.length*rectangle.breadth
end
data_obj = __init__()

r = get_area(data_obj)
end
```

Please do suggest an appropriate approach to achieve the python example in Julia.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bold move to just literally translate from Python.  It doesn't work that way, obviously.

However, the following should be enough:

```
struct Rectangle{T}
    length::T
    breadth::T
    height::T
end

area(rectangle) = rectangle.length * rectangle.breadth

r = Rectangle(160, 20, 1000)
println(area(r))
```

(The type parameter is not something you asked for, but recommended.)

Now, if you need to do something more than simply assign the fields, you can write an outer constructor:

```
function Rectangle(l, b, h)
    ...
    return Rectangle(l, b, h)
end
```

But there's no need for this unless some actual logic is required.

Comment: may i know what is the use `__init__()` in julia base?

Comment: Oooh... that's something completely different and used for [module initialization](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Module-initialization-and-precompilation). Used rarely, so I didn't even think of it.